# Webframe executeJavascript pass down object

Tags: electron

I am adding [`contextIsolation`](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content) since I am loading remote content in my webview.

Using `webFrame.executeJavascript(...)` from inside a preload script, how do I pass down an un-serializable object to the inner webpage's context?

More concretely, here is my example:

preload.js:

```
// In the preload.js context
const { ipcRenderer, webFrame } = require('electron')
const ipc = {
  send (data) {
    ipcRenderer.sendToHost(...)
  }
}
// Now I want to pass down ipc to the webpage's context
// This webpage is expecting window.myApp.ipc, so that it could use it like window.myApp.ipc.send(...)
webFrame.executeJavaScript(`window.myApp.ipc = ${ipc}`); // Doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to send nonserializable object via executejavascript. If your preload script is for webview's, you can attach some object into `window` for global access.

Comment: Looking at https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#3-enable-context-isolation-for-remote-content, if I say `window.bar = 'bar';` in my preload script, `window.bar` will be undefined inside my webview, with context isolation on.